# Who is the real creator of heaven and earth as per the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, gods, vedic-gods, creation

In different hymns Vedas talk about different creators of heaven and earth. How to reconcile these differences? Who is the real creator?

### Indra

> Rig Veda 8.36.4 “Creator of the heaven, **creator of the earth, O Śatakratu,** drink Soma to make thee glad.”

### Purusha

> Yajur Veda 31.12 “Forth from his navel came mid-air; the sky was fashioned from his head; Earth from his feet…”

### Vishvakarma

> Rig Veda 10.82.1 “THE Father of the eye, the Wise in spirit, **created both these worlds submerged in fatness.** Then when the eastern ends were firmly fastened, the heavens and the earth were far extended.”

### Aja

> Atharva Veda 9.5.20 “This Unborn cleft apart in the beginning: his breast became the earth, his back was heaven…”

### Dhatar

> Rig Veda 10.90.3 “…**He formed in order Heaven and Earth**, the regions of the air, and light.”

### Tvastar

> Rig Veda 10.110.9 “Hotar more skilled in sacrifice, bring hither with speed to-day God Tvaṣṭar, thou who knowest. **Even him who formed these two, the Earth and Heaven** the Parents, with their forms, and every creature.”

### Ribhus

> Rig Veda 4.34.9 “Ṛbhus, who helped their Parents and the Aśvins, who formed the Milch-cow and the pair of horses, Made armour, **set the heaven and earth** asunder,—far- reaching Heroes, they have made good offspring.”

### Hiranyagarba

> Rig Veda 10.121.9 “Neer may he harm us who is **earth’s Begetter,** nor he whose laws are sure, **the heavens’ Creator,** He who brought forth the great and lucid waters. What God shall we adore with our oblation?”

Comment: Narayana is the creator. All these are just different names of Narayana.

Comment: God is formless and nameless in reality. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35075/16530  When the infinite God is given a form and a name it makes the infinite finite leading to confusions, quarrels among its worshippers who cram without understanding like different religions and sects of today. But the worship of formless is impossible for mind dominated weak souls as their mind is not concentrated just like a mind dominated child can easily understand something through images and fantasies but fail to understand through pure logic.

Comment: Thats why world with images is created in first place else if God was some theory, God could have shown Vedas in the dreams of everyone why would he even be involved in creating never ending yet temporary material realm. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/12/verse/5 Thats why Islam forbid from giving any image to God but they fail to understand that creation/nature is the creator itself hence mindlessly kill innocent in the name of Jihad. Purush/God and Prakriti/world are one. In Kaliyuga fools are in majority, thats why the most secretive knowledge of Vedas is openly accessible to all

Comment: Even your and my and all other bodies are temporary and finite, so are their egos and intellect. How can you grasp infinite through finite words and forms. Thats why Brahmgyanis like Dakshinamurti goes into silence while explaining truth to their disciples. https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/חסד/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rig Veda [2.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02001.htm) says

> 2 Thine is the Herald's task and Cleanser's duly timed; Leader art
>   thou, and Kindler for the pious man. Thou art Director, thou the
>   ministering Priest: **thou art the Brahman,** Lord and Master in our home.
>
> 3 Hero of Heroes, Agni! Thou art Indra, thou art Viṣṇu of the Mighty
>   Stride, adorable: Thou, Brahmaṇaspati, the Brahman finding wealth:
>   thou, O Sustainer, with thy wisdom tendest us.

---

In the 1st mantra, AGNI was eulogised as BRAHMAN,  the Almighty.  In the subsequent mantras AGNI was eulogised as INDRA, VISHNU, etc.

So the names (AGNI, INDRA, VISHNU, etc.) used in the Veda, are epithets of same Almighty.

So it was the Almighty God, who was creator,  as per Veda

Comment: If all Vedic gods are same, why does the Anukramani list the gods separately?

Comment: 100 million dollars question! Good observation @sv.

Comment: @sv. Yes, why even mention so many gods if all gods are the same? And then make a couple of statements here and there that truth is one? That's a very very very very indirect way to show that there is only one god.

Comment: Brahman was this before; therefore it knew even the Ātma (soul, himself). And whoever among the gods had this enlightenment, also became That. It is the same with the sages, the same with men. Whoever knows the self as “I am Brahman,” becomes all this universe. Even the gods cannot prevail against him, for he becomes their Ātma. Now, if a man worships another god, thinking: “He is one and I am another,” he does not know. He is like an animal to the gods. As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve the gods.

Comment: Even if one animal is taken away, it causes anguish; how much more so when many are taken away? Therefore it is not pleasing to the gods that men should know this.- Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10 ,    Today, its because of Vedanta that people are able to say."All Gods are same", because in Kaliyuga its open to study by anyone but this knowledge was highly confidential in earlier ages.Whoever will understand this will become Brahman/God. If all will realize it, earth and heaven will be empty of slave jivas-devas.In Kaliyuga, people are atheist, low intellect thats why cant grasp immortality.